# Identifying this "Transistor", in this particular circuit

Tags: transistors, identification, robotics, analysis, reverse-engineering

I'm in FIRST robotics, and I've been helping with our robot over the past few weeks. Every robot (in FIRST) is required to have a status light, which is fancy-ily connected to some other gear. Regardless, each robot has a cRIO, which is essentially a robust programmable microcontroller, with some other functionality as well. A few weeks in, the status light quit working, completely. Normally it has different modes of blinking, with different rates, but I was getting nothing. Yesterday, I popped open the cap on the "digital sidecar", which the light is attached to, and found that there was a blown IC. After some analysis, I believe it to be an amplifier of sorts for controlling the 12VDC connection to the status light. In the schematic for the digital sidecar (breakout board essentially, with protection), the device is labeled Q1. The package on the board is missing the part number, as it was blown off. I do however know that it's branded Fairchild, and has a date/info code of "PAKAA".

Here's a link to the circuit schematic:http://team358.org/files/programming/ControlSystem2009-/SideCar.pdf

The schematic is on the last page.

If you could help in any way to identify this package, and tell me if I could have a viable substitute, I would much appreciate it. Even if I don't have a replacement, I can order one and replace it on the day of the competition, as today is the last day we can work on the robot before it's sealed until game day.

Comment: On that Schematic it has Q1 as [FDS8817NZ](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/FD/FDS8817NZ.html) a 30 volt n-channel power MOSFET.

Comment: So you have a broken part labelled Q1 (that you have correctly identified as a fairchild part) and you have a schematic that tells you what Q1 is. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I didn't know it was anywhere else in the other diagrams. What your missing is me missing sleep. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1 in the schematic is a [FDS8817NZ](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FD/FDS8817NZ.pdf).

It's for reverse input voltage protection. It may or may not be the only thing blown up.

Comment: How did you find this out? Just wondering. Thank you!

Comment: I just opened the schematic you linked (Page 3) and "Ctrl-F Q1". The function is also clearly marked, and is a standard building block.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it was in the other diagrams. Thanks again lol.